# Compare two collections optimization

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, collections

I need to optimize the code in comparing and manipulation of its values.I have a two collection of data, let say collection A and collection B. In collection A is the list of all existing data, and in collection B is the consolidated of existing data and the new data to be added. Now, I need to check if collection B exists in collection A, if it exists I need to set or modify the specific data of collection A with the updated data of collection B. If the specific data of Collection B is not exists in A then I need to add it to collection A.

Here is the code that I have.

```
  public CollectionA Save(List<CollectionB> collectionb)
  var collectionA = collectionA.GetAll().OrderByDescending(x => x.SortOrder);
 foreach (var b in collectionb)
            {
                if (b.Id == 0)
                {
                    a.Add(b);
                    continue;
                }
                foreach (var a in collectionA.Where(aa => aa.Id == b.Id))
                {
                    a.ZoneCode = b.ZoneCode;
                    a.SortOrder = b.SortOrder;
                    a.Point1 = b.Point1;
                    a.Point2 = b.Point2;
                    a.Point3 = b.Point3;
                    a.RangeSpread = b.RangeSpread;
                    a.MidpointDifferential = b.MidpointDifferential;
                    a.AnnualIncentivePercent = b.AnnualIncentivePercent;
                    a.AnnualIncentiveAmount = b.AnnualIncentiveAmount;
                    a.GradeMisc1 = b.GradeMisc1;
                    a.GradeMisc2 = b.GradeMisc2;
                    a.ZoneComment = b.ZoneComment;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [.FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to look for an item with the same ID. If the item exists, remove it from the main collection, then add the new ( / updated) item. If there's no matching ID, just add the new item.

```
foreach (var b in collectionB)
{
   var itemToUpdate = collectionA.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == b.Id);
   if (itemToUpdate != null)
   {
      collectionA.Remove(itemToUpdate);
   }
   collectionA.Add(b);
}
```

edit:

You can use the [.SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) method if your list is expected to contain an items with unique ID's. The difference is, .SingleOrDefault will throw an exception if there are multiple items with the same ID.

Comment: @Marton- is this possible using LINQ?

Comment: This isn't a very good idea. You should create dictionaries of both collections, indexed by id, to have a linear seek time.

Comment: @RobertGiesecke What if he *has* to work with an existing List<>, because he gets them from an external library or service? The seek time is linear anyways, so I don't understand your downvote.

Comment: @ Robert Giesecke- the existing functionality is using list, if I will make it a Dictionary then I need to convert it first from List to Dictionary before I can proceed to your suggestion.

Comment: @user3098871 Yes, .FirstOrDefault or .SingleOrDefault works on LINQ queries too.

Comment: you can always create a dictionary from a list.  var byId = collectionA.ToDictionary(k => k.Id) - I'll post some sample code...

Comment: @RobertGiesecke If optimization turns out to be necessary, then that might help. I tend not to pre-optimize too much, if it increases code complexity. Also, from the SO help center: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."  That's why I'm asking why the downvote. You can post your idea as an answer if you think it's better.

Comment: Well, he did ask for an optimization. Code that performs O(n²) without good reason is kinda sloppy in my book.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 2 large-ish lists and you want to find the changes between without actually comparing everyone against everyone.

You should create 2 dictionaries and index them by their key values. C# anonymous types are a good fit for this, because the compiler already generates GetHashCode and Equals based on the values.

This is a rather naive approach (as it could easily throw OutOfMemoryException because it does everything in-memory), but it should perform *much* better than just comparing everything from A with everything from B.
This will only compare the values where the keys are the same:

```
class ListComparisonResult<TKey>
{
  public IList<TKey> NewKeys { get; private set; }
  public IList<TKey> OldKeys { get; private set; }
  public IList<TKey> ChangedKeys { get; private set; }

  public ListComparisonResult(IList<TKey> newKeys, IList<TKey> oldKeys, IList<TKey> changedKeys)
  {
    NewKeys = new ReadOnlyCollection<TKey>(newKeys);
    OldKeys = new ReadOnlyCollection<TKey>(oldKeys);
    ChangedKeys = new ReadOnlyCollection<TKey>(changedKeys);
  }
}

ListComparisonResult<TKey> GetChanges<TRow, TKey, TValues>(
  IEnumerable<TRow> collectionA, 
  IEnumerable<TRow> collectionB,  
  Func<TRow, TKey> keySelector, 
  Func<TRow, TValues> comparableValuesSelector)
{
  var byId = new
  {
    A = collectionA.ToDictionary(keySelector),
    B = collectionB.ToDictionary(keySelector),
  };

  var sameIds = new HashSet<TKey>(byId.A.Keys.Where(byId.B.ContainsKey));

  var changedIds = (from id in sameIds
                    let a = byId.A[id]
                    let b = byId.B[id]
                    where !comparableValuesSelector(a).Equals(comparableValuesSelector(b))
                    select id).ToList();

  var oldIds = byId.A.Keys.Where(id => !byId.B.ContainsKey(id)).ToList();
  var newIds = byId.B.Keys.Where(id => !byId.A.ContainsKey(id)).ToList();
  return new ListComparisonResult<TKey>(newIds, oldIds, changedIds);
}
```

This is how it could be used:

```
var r = new Random();
var collectionA = (from id in Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000)
                   select new
                   {
                     ID = id, 
                     Value1 = r.Next(1, 3),
                     Value2 = r.Next(0, 1) == 1,
                   }).ToList();

var collectionB = (from id in Enumerable.Range(58945, 1000000)
                   select new
                   {
                     ID = id, 
                     Value1 = r.Next(1, 3),
                     Value2 = r.Next(0, 1) == 1,
                   }).ToList();

var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var changes = GetChanges(collectionA, collectionB, t => t.ID, t => new{t.Value1, t.Value2});
timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(new
{
  changedIds = changes.ChangedKeys.Count, 
  newIds = changes.NewKeys.Count, 
  oldIds = changes.OldKeys.Count, 
  timer.ElapsedMilliseconds
});
```

Comment: +1 for the effort to provide a speed optimized solution.